# Adding new data to an array, Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm just starting out and I'm trying to fix this error in my code. I'm fetching data from my DRF API and mapping it out into a Material UI table. That all works fine but when I add a new item and push that to the array using the addImport function, it gives me the key error and I can't work out how to pass the key through.

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

```
export default function ImportsList() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Import[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCars = async () => {
      const data: Import[] = await API.listImports();
      setData(data);
    };
    fetchCars();
  }, []);

  function addImport(request: Import) {
    data.push(request);
    setData([...data]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <AddImportDialog
        onImportCreated={(i: Import) => addImport(i)}
      ></AddImportDialog>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table size="small" aria-label="Holdings table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Make</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Model</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Short Tagline</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Chassis</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Customer</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Budget</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Started</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Owner</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Status</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Edit</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {data?.map((i) => (
              <TableRow key={i?.id}>
                <TableCell>{i?.make}</TableCell>
```

It continues to map the values below. There's no error if I remove the addImport function.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: in the line ```<TableRow key={i?.id}>``` you are mapping the key. Make sure to add unique ```id``` attribute whenever you add a new object in the array.

Comment: one more thing your ```addImport``` function will not update the ```data``` as your ```data.push(request);``` line is not going to update the array.

Comment: It does update the array, it just gives the key error.

Answer (score 1):

The key prop is required to establish relation between the component and the DOM. React uses this relation to determine if the component should be re-rendered or not.

Comment: Ok, so logging request tells me the id is undefined as its not yet on the API. So I need to call the fetchCars again after the add I think?

Answer (score 0):

Lose the addImport function totally and set [data] in the final array of useEffect was the answer.